# Azure SDK 2.2 in Production: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have read about this problem on several other threads both on StackOverflow and other sites. None of the other solutions have solved my problem and most are outdated, referencing old versions of the Azure SDK.

I have a typical Azure website role deployed to Azure that uses `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` to log trace messages. When tracing occurs, it appears as though `DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` is using the `RoleEnvironment` class, which in turn tries to load the apparently non-existent `msshrtmi.dll`. Here is a portion of the stack trace that is being logged to the file system in Azure:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;msshrtmi, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeEnvironment() +0
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment..cctor() +747

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for &#39;Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment&#39; threw an exception.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_IsAvailable() +0
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultStartupInfoForCurrentRoleInstance() +23
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener..ctor() +34

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
   System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData) +9004943
   System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() +110
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() +989
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() +252
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() +331
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message) +161
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.AzureApplicationSettings..ctor() +437
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings() +137
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(String name) +27
   TankSoft.EverMarket.EverMarketPrereleaseRole.Endpoints.Api.Notify..ctor() +40
   lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) +60
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +315
```

Various threads have mentioned how I need to clean this DLL from my bin folder, but the DLL is not being copied in the first place. I suspect this has to do with me running under Azure SDK 2.2 and not 1.x. I realize I can reference the DLL directly but I feel that I should not have to do this in order to deploy what is a quite normal project to Azure. Why is Microsoft not automatically detecting that my project requires this file and deploying the correct file for me? This is maddening.

Let me also say that the project I am publishing is *not a Cloud Service* but rather a regular Azure website project.

Has anyone *running Azure SDK 2.x* managed to solve this issue? What were the exact steps you followed?

Comment: The type of things keep occuring. I have been using Azure since SDK 1.7. And in my experience I cannot reliably tell how long deploying takes. Stuff might run locally as a "traditional site"and in the azure  emulator, but then when you run it on Azure all kinds of "weird" errors occur. This can be very stressful if you're doing short sprints, and deploying takes days instead of minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feels like a hack but it was the only way I could think of to solve this issue.

1. Open Configuration Manager for the solution
2. Select the Debug solution configuration
3. Create a new solution platform for x64
4. For each web role and worker role project, set the platform to x64
5. Remove the Any CPU solution platform
6. Make the same changes to the Release configuration
7. Add a reference to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\runtimes\base\x64\msshrtmi.dll`
8. Set `Copy Local` on the new reference to `True`

[image: Configuration Manager]

**EDIT**: I ended up removing the code that was checking RoleEnvironment; instead, I'm relying on Web.config/App.config transforms to modify behavior at runtime. This removes the dependency on msshrtmi.dll.

Comment: Note, Azure Websites are 32-bit by default, so you should select **x86** instead of x64 in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same error when publishing a Web App. After trying every other solution above, the following finally worked for me:

In the Azure Portal, select your Web App. Select 'Settings > Application settings'. Change the Platform value from 32-bit to 64-bit. Re-publish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using SDK 2.2 and deploying a website using Visual Studio 2013. In previous projects I had the following lines in my Postbuild event commandline:

```
cd $(OutDir)
del msshrtmi.dll
```

But this doesn't solve my problem anymore. The dll is not being copied into the bin folder anymore.

Comment: You should've probably posted a comment on the question instead of an answer, but yes, I noticed the same thing. The *correct* file would have to be copied to bin, which feels like a hack that I'm unwilling to do. Really, the SDK should be handling this for me.

Comment: You are right! It should've been a comment. I think I was multi-tasking a little too much ;) So hopefully a mod can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter the same problem. I have Azure SDK 2.5 installed on my machine, but the project is created on SDK 2.2 and previously SDK 2.2 was installed. The problem is the SDK 2.2 is removed from GAC and its pointing to 2.5. Therefore, I referenced Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime 2.2 and mark as "Copy to local=true", the Assembly has dependencies on "msshrtmi.dll", so i put postbuild event on my project. Therefore, "msshrtmi.dll" will be copied.

Remember, you don't need to reference "msshrtmi.dll".

I hope this will help.

Comment: This happened to me as well.  I had to re-add msshrtmi.dll back into the gac.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing 
"For each web role and worker role project, set the platform to x64 & Remove the Any CPU solution platform" is not required.

Important part is setting all the reffered Azure SDK assemblies and any 3rd party Dlls which are not part of .NET framework to mark them as CopyLocal = true; This solved the problem for me. 
And for more error information keep checking the Event Logs of Azure Virtual Machine under Azure Event section. This will give you idea what could be possible reason for your build failure or any other unhandled errors while application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all other versions of Azure SDK and make sure that you have the latest.

This is a common conflict that makes Visual Studio reference part of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime (in this case the msshrtmi.dll) to an older version of the SDK.