# Azure RoleEnvironment alternative

Tags: azure

I have continual problems with msshrtmi every time I upgrade Azure SDK. Common problem is this one

[Azure SDK 2.2 in Production: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649185/azure-sdk-2-2-in-production-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-msshrtmi-or-one-o)

It seems the best answer is to not reference RoleEnvironment anymore and remove the dependency. What is the best way to check if running in staging or production other than this? Currently I am just doing

```
    private static bool GetIsRunningInAzure()
    {
        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable && !RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated) 
            return true;   
        return false;        
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a direct answer for you (I ran into this same problem just now), but I *did* fix this issues with msshrtmi by adding direct references to the SDK binaries for x86 (Not x64 for me!). The only issue is that right now it's always returning `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable==false`.

Comment: I find if I deploy to Azure web sites it requires the x86 version but if I deploy to Azure web roles it requires x64. It seems random. I wish they would get rid of msshrtmi binary specific.

Comment: I'm using an Azure Mobile Service and it seems to require x86, even though it is a web role, but has that issue listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that ALL your projects are referencing correct Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime (from the correct SDK's folder).  Usually mis-referenced Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime is the culprit of msshrtmi errors (outside of not running inside Azure/emulator)

Comment: Is there any easy way to diagnose this? I dread upgrading to new versions due to the inevitability of this error.

Comment: Just inspect the references path for the dll mentioned. if it matches correct folder you're ok. likely you have some non starting project referencing a different version