# RoleEnvironment issues in .NET backend for Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Service using the new .NET Backend for it. In `Global.asax` (application initialization), I am trying to call `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` to see if it is currently running in the cloud or not.

So far, I have had nothing but issues with it.

With just a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime`, I get a TypeInitializationException due to a lack of reference (or failure to load) `msshrtmi`.

If I add a manual reference to `msshrtmi` one of two things happens:

If it's the x86 reference, it works just fine but throws warnings when deploying. It runs fine and doesn't crash when accessing `RoleEnvironment`, but `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` always returns `false`.

If it's the x64 reference, it throws the same exception as if it were not there.

I have cleaned (and deleted bin/obj) before deploying, deployed via the could service or publishing directly from the project, and have ensured that they are all set to `Copy Local = True`. Nothing seems to help.

So, I need help with one of two things (from what I've been able to tell).

1) A way to determine if the Mobile Service is currently running in the cloud (or cloud emulator) without using `RoleEnvironment`.

2) A way to get `msshrtmi` working for my Mobile Service.

One last note: as reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926625/azure-roleenvironment-alternative), I have indeed made sure that they are all referencing the *same* copy of either x64 or x86 `Windows.Azure.ServiceRuntime` and `msshrtmi`.

As a last last thought, I wonder if the Azure Mobile Service is *not* running in a Role, even if it is set as a Web Role. If so, I will need a `RoleEnvironment` alternative.